# Facebook OG Meta Tags Not Working

Tags: facebook, meta

So we've debuted our new website: http://www.lumativ.com and for some reason, I can't get the Open Graph tags to allow our social networking links to show up properly on Facebook. I have two questions:

**Does it matter that the site redirects to https://?**

**Is there anything wrong with these OG tags?**

```
<meta property="og:title" content="LUMATIV - E5 Snapback">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.lumativ.com/">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.lumativ.com/images/2014/promo/lumativ-2014-facebook.jpg">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="LUMATIV - E5 Snapback">
```

Thank you in advance. I've reviewed other posts on this and read through the docs on Open Graph and nothing is taking.

Comment: This is what Facebook sees: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lumativ.com%2F and as you can see you have a body tag in the top that makes facebook not see your meta tags.

Comment: You are a miracle! thank You!

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I had an error in my php that was throwing an "unseen" error into my HTML. WizKid got it!